# How to GET data from single value inside JSON Object from JSON Array?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin beginner and trying to create a code to fetch data from JSON.

I'd like to fetch the data from "value" inside "forecastMaxtemp".

Here is my code.  I am tried as below but not successful.

```
...
Response.Listener { response ->
temp.text = 
response.getJSONArray (name"weatherForecast").
    getJSONObject(0).
    getJSONObject("forecastMaxtemp").
    getString(name"value")
},
```

JSON Data

```
{"generalSituation":No Alarm",
"weatherForecast":[{
    "forecastDate":"20211004",
    "week":"Monday",
    "forecastWind":"East force 4 to 5.",
    "forecastWeather":"Sunny periods.",
    "forecastMaxtemp":{"value":31,"unit":"C"},
    "forecastMintemp":{"value":27,"unit":"C"},
...
...
]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion How can I modify it If I would like to get both values in one JSONObject ("value" and "unit")

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has an issue, I think this is the right format:

```
{
  "generalSituation": "No Alarm",
  "weatherForecast": [
    {
      "forecastDate": "20211004",
      "week": "Monday",
      "forecastWind": "East force 4 to 5.",
      "forecastWeather": "Sunny periods.",
      "forecastMaxtemp": {
        "value": 31,
        "unit": "C"
      },
      "forecastMintemp": {
        "value": 27,
        "unit": "C"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to get the value from "forecastMaxtemp",

```
val json = JSONObject("YOUR_JSON")
val obj = json.getJSONArray("weatherForecast").get(0) as JSONObject
val value = obj.getJSONObject("forecastMaxtemp").getInt("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

`{"value":31,"unit":"C"}` here `31` is int, so use `getInt()` function.

```
response.getJSONArray ("weatherForecast").
getJSONObject(0).
getJSONObject("forecastMaxtemp").
getInt("value")
}
```